# MySQL : LEFT JOIN for 4 tables which are connected to each other

Tags: php, mysql, rest, api, join

I have 4 tables as below:

**1) courses**

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | Name
   -------------------------------
   | 1                  | Course 1
   | 2                  | Course 2
   | 3                  | Course 3
```

**2) countries**

```
   | IDPrimary Key | Name
   -------------------------------
   | 1                  | Country 1
   | 2                  | Country 2
   | 3                  | Course 3
```

**3) universities**

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | Name           | country_id
   ---------------------------------------------------
   | 1                  | University 1   | 1
   | 2                  | University 2   | 1
   | 3                  | University 3   | 3
```

**4) university_courses**

```
   | ID - > Primary Key | university_id  | course_id
   ----------------------------------------------
   | 1                  | 1              | 2
   | 2                  | 3              | 2
   | 3                  | 3              | 3
```

Now, I need to create one REST API in **core PHP** for android app in that I will get two parameters **`country_id`** and **`course_id`**. Both will contain multiple values like **`country_id = "3,4,5"`** and **`course_id = "1,6,8"`**.

I have to response all the **related universities** according to the **country** and **course**.

I have tried below query but i am not getting desired output so please help me if anyone have idea for my problem.

```
SELECT * FROM universities LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = universities.country_id LEFT JOIN university_courses ON universiity_courses.university_id = universities.id LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = university_courses.course_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET(universities.country_id, ?) AND FIND_IN_SET(university_courses.course_id, ?)
```

If `course_id = 1,2` and `country_id = 2,3`, my desired output should be:

```
| university_id |
| 3             |
```

**UPDATE:**

Above issue is solved but now facing new issue is getting same `university` multiple time in result like:

if `course_id = 2,3` I am getting response as:

```
|university_id  |
------------------
|3              |
|3              |
```

For that I have used `GROUP BY` clause but getting `500 Internal Server Error` if I remove `GROUP BY` It will work fine What can be the issue?

My new query is as below:

```
SELECT * FROM universities LEFT JOIN university_courses ON university_courses.university_id = universities.id LEFT JOIN courses ON courses.id = university_courses.course_id LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.id = universities.country_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET(university_courses.course_id, ?) AND FIND_IN_SET(universities.country_id, ?) GROUP BY university_courses.university_id
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample .. your actual result and your expected  result

Answer (score 0):

use LEFT OUTER JOIN not LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT * FROM universities LEFT OUTER JOIN countries ON countries.id = universities.country_id LEFT OUTER JOIN university_courses ON universiity_courses.university_id = universities.id LEFT OUTER JOIN courses ON courses.id = university_courses.course_id WHERE FIND_IN_SET(universities.country_id, ?) AND FIND_IN_SET(university_courses.course_id, ?)
```

Comment: Okay! right now LEFT JOIN is also working for me but now facing new issue: if `course_id = 2,3` then am getting `university_id = 3` twice

Comment: I have tried `GROUP BY` but getting `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`